# Change wordpress post content url from mysql?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Where do I go in the Mysql database to change the path of the media that are already inside the post instead of having to each post one by one and change the links url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great plugin, I use it all the time
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/

you just tell it what you want to change and it will go through your whole db find/replace.  totally recommended.

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSS THANK YOU :)